# Bluetooth mouse not working even is connected, paired, trusted

Tags: mouse, bluetooth, asus

I have new [ASUS ZenBook UX410UA](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks/ASUS-ZenBook-UX410UA/) and Microsoft Designer Bluetooth Mouse.

I was able to pair, connect and trust Bluetooth mouse, **but it mostly doesn't work**. 
Sometimes mouse works only few seconds after login, sometimes few minutes. Than mouse cursor will get stuck and only sometimes helps toggle on/off Bluetooth, sometimes logout, sometimes nothing and reboot is needed. Absolutely not reliable.

```
petr@UX410:~$ bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller F4:8C:50:AC:FE:12 UX410 [default]
[NEW] Device F4:48:0D:AC:6B:6E Designer Mouse
[bluetooth]# info F4:48:0D:AC:6B:6E
Device F4:48:0D:AC:6B:6E
Name: Designer Mouse
Alias: Designer Mouse
Appearance: 0x03c2
Icon: input-mouse
Paired: yes
Trusted: yes
Blocked: no
Connected: yes
LegacyPairing: no
UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Battery Service           (0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
UUID: Human Interface Device    (00001812-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
[bluetooth]# version
Version 5.37
```

I have connected/paired thru `bluetoothctl` utility, as Bluetooth section in *Wingpanel* or *Switchboard Bluetooth settings* not worked well for me.

`lshw` output here at https://pastebin.com/uuy41GhD

**Any suggestions how to get this work**, or is this known "in development" stage?
Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem with a wired mouse, after last Elementary update 4.1 It works for a short time, then i nerd to force with "pkill wingpanel" and start working for a short time again...
I'm so nerd, how i can update the kernel to 4.8.? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Solved after update to new kernel 4.8 {linux-generic-hwe-16.04}